# Splitting phrases into words using R

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have a search queries report from Google Analytics which gives me the phrases on which a user searched. I have it in a dataframe, the first column of which looks a bit like this:

```
    search.queries
1   the quick
2   brown fox jumps
3   over the 
4   lazy
5   dog
```

Ideally I would very much like it in the form:

```
    words
1   the 
2   quick
3   brown
4   fox
...
```

Any help would be very much appreciated

Kind Regards

G

Comment: the other columns of the original dataframe are surplus to requirements and can be ignored

Answer (score 4):

Just do splitting.

```
> df <- data.frame(names = c("the quick","brown fox", "over the lazy", "dog"))
> data.frame(names = unlist(strsplit(as.character(df$names), "\\s+")))
  names
1   the
2 quick
3 brown
4   fox
5  over
6   the
7  lazy
8   dog
```

Comment: we have the exact same answer. I will delete mine to avoid duplicates.